# Is it "crowd" or "croud?"

Tags: grammar, differences, word-usage

In my mind, I want to spell it "croud" when I'm talking about a verb and "crowd" as a noun, but I think the only correct form is "crowd." A quick Google search of "croud" showed a Wiktionary page saying that it's an obsolete spelling of "crowd," but I didn't see much else to support this in other sites. Are both correct? Is it only "crowd" that's correct?

Comment: Lots of words spelled with "ow" have obsolete spellings with "ou", and vice versa. English spelling hasn't always been standardized.

Comment: @sumelic could you give me an example?

Comment: E.g. the Oxford English Dictionary gives the following list of spellings that have been used for the word *shout* at some point in time (the abbreviation "ME" stands for "Middle English"): "ME schoute, ME–15 shoute, schowte, ME–16 showt(e, schout, 15 schowt, 16 shoot(e, 15– shout". It doesn't mean that you can use any spelling other than "shout" today. Likewise, the OED lists the following historical spelling variants for *gown*: "ME–15 goun(e, ME–16 gowne, (15 Sc. gounn, 17–18 vulgar gownd), ME– gown." But no spelling other than "gown" is considered standard in present-day English.

Comment: Certainly "it is not correct" is the right answer,  however I would like to know the 'why' myself if there were a linguistic rule that the transformation followed.  However .. there is a linguistics stackoverflow community .   I can think of loud , or cloud (which works as a noun and a verb),  which haven't changed.. but 'plow' seems to have picked up a 'w' from a previous plough .. yet the d in plowed is only from the standard past tense convention.

Comment: @Tom22 I think you are asking a different question than the one stated in this question.  The question you seem curious about is the etymology of the word with topical examples as compared to like-spelled words.  I think the answer is in the question and this should be closed.

Comment: I have never seen that spelling used (at least not in a context where I would have trusted it to be "correct").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct spelling is ["crowd"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crowd) for both the noun and the verb. Or at least that's how it is now.

Wiktionary is correct that at one point in time it was spelled "croud". Because this spelling is no longer used, it will not be listed in regular dictionaries. According to the Oxford English Dictionary, this spelling was used 1500-1800 (the exact range depends on which noun or verb sense we're talking about). Here is an example of this old spelling from **1709**:

> There croud into his Mind, the *Ideas* which compose the Visible Man, in company with all the other *Ideas* of Sight perceiv'd at the same time.
>   <sub>[An essay towards a new theory of vision.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/ecco/004848514.0001.000/1:5.110?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)</sub>

It's important to note that using this spelling nowadays is always an error. It's not used even when trying to imitate older English spellings.

Comment: "It's not used even when trying to imitate older English spellings": but it _is_ used when adopting _actual_ older English spellings, since it is one.

Answer (score 1):

Crowd is the correct spelling regardless of historical spellings, to which there are many words in the vernacular that have transitioned through syntactical updates.

In the here-and-now, it is `crowd`:
See Interest over time on Google Trends for crowd, croud - Worldwide, Past 12 months - https://g.co/trends/SqAhk

Comment: more elaboration would be good and use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: This 'answer' is a comment.  The OP was a bit round about yet made it clear that he had done some research and knew that the alternatives were incorrect yet really more fishing for why the old meaning was not acceptable.

Comment: @Tom22 I don't think that's clear and if that's the case I would request that the question be closed or at least edited.  The title clearly states — "is it crowd or croud?" and yes has already answered that in the OP.  No offense, but Laurel's answer did not provide much information over what the OP stated, which I find redundant.  The question seemed to be drawing for affirmation, which I supplied in an answer; granted, which appears as a comment due to its brevity, but is a valid answer based on the question.  For these reasons, I would request the question be closed.

Comment: I agree that as you put in a new comment, "the answer was in the question" .  I also agree that the other answer isn't much better beyond affirmation as you point out. (also agree that I clearly was suggesting a different question than asked as an alternative to this one which should be closed as is)  All my comment might self destruct

Comment: But I think you should ask that question as now im curious :)